# the possibility of a "for" loop self.ids kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to loop for an API to return multiple aircraft position coordinates, but when I run only 1 coordinate result.

my question is how can i configure it to be able to do a for loop and show all the positions of the aircraft?

**main.py**

```
class ExpertServer(Screen):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        data = get_json()

        for i in data:
            self.ids.markerview.lat = i['latitude']
            self.ids.markerview.lon = i['longitude']
            self.ids.markerview.angle = i['heading']


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('main.kv')

        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(Menu(name='menu'))
        self.sm.add_widget(ExpertServer(name='expert'))
        return self.sm


MyApp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
#:import MapView kivy_garden.mapview.MapView

<ExpertServer>:
    name: 'expert'
    FloatLayout:
        MapView:            
            zoom: 3
            lat: 0
            lon: 0
            double_tap_zoom: True                
            MapMarkerPopup:
                id: markerview
                lat: 0
                lon: 0
                angle: 180
                source: "map_marker.png"
                canvas.before:
                    PushMatrix
                    Rotate:
                        angle: self.angle
                        origin: self.center
                canvas.after:
                    PopMatrix
```

**result:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91clR.png)

Comment: `self.ids.markerview` should be a list, not a single object that you're overriding

Comment: I don't get your logic completely, how can you show all the data in just one view ? The way I can think of is, it is actually showing all data sequentially while iterating over loop and stops with the data last encountered.